# How to find memory timings that work so the memory operates at optimum speed (Mhz)

Tags: windows-installer, memory-timings

So I treated myself to a new gaming PC this year.
After having used my old 8350 for around 5 years.

I purchased the components and built the pc myself,
as opposed to buying a ready made unit over the counter.

I have resigned myself to the fact that after 5 bios updates, 
it is most unlikely that my memory will be supported (be on the QVL list) by the particular motherboard I have.

I have browsed the internet to find out as much as possible about the particular memory kit I have bought.

- I found a pdf which relates to the memory chips installed on the
  memory modules. [Datasheet](http://www.datasheets360.com/part/detail/h5an8g8nmfr-tfc/5095368579431044469/?alternatePartManufacturerId=0)
- I have the timings as advertised by the memory
  manufacturer.
- I can use the bios (though I am green in this
  department) to custom set the memory timings.

The problem is...
I do not know or have any idea what the timings should be in order to run the memory at optimum.

***Is there a memory timings calculator anywhere?
where I can enter the specs and it can churn out a timing sequence?***

**The motherboard is:**
MSI X370 Gaming Pro Carbon 
[Manufacturers Motherboard Website Page](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/X370-GAMING-PRO-CARBON.html#productFeature-section)

**The Bios Version is:**
7A32v15 (can be found on link above)

**The CPU is:**
AMD Ryzen 1800X AM4[Manufacturers CPU Website Page](http://www.amd.com/en/products/cpu/amd-ryzen-7-1800x)

**The memory kit in question is:**
CORSAIR VENGEANCE CKMGX324M2B3000C15 DDR4 3000Mhz. 
It is 2 modules of 16gb each total of 32gb
[Manufacturers Memory Website Page](http://www.corsair.com/en-gb/vengeance-lpx-32gb-2x16gb-ddr4-dram-3000mhz-c15-memory-kit-black-cmk32gx4m2b3000c15)

**The advertised memory timings for kit are:** 
15-17-17-17-35
Yet, when I enter those timings the system crashes and refuses to boot up. I then have to reset the bios via the jumper.

So how do I calculate the optimum  timings for the memory kit given all the info in the attached files?

I've beat my head trying to figure it out and come to the conclusion that age is getting the better of me and my brain is not complying.

Thank You for reading.
PS
Though I'm comfortable with windows and pc's
hardware and bios are new territory for me,
nor do I know anything about over clocking.

PPS
In case I haven't phrased the question properly...
How do I calculate memory timings that will allow me to run the memory at 3000Mhz(1500Mhz) or near as dammit given the info I have (see links)

DocZaf

Answer (score 0):

And not one person responded
How very helpfull ^^
I suggest you to take a look at this site http://www.overclock.net/t/1624603/rog-crosshair-vi-overclocking-thread/
Loads of info that you may find usefull

Comment: "And not one person responded How very helpfull ^^ I suggest you to take a look at this site" clearly nobody knew the answer to the qanswer question.  With that said what could be a helpful answer is limited to being unhelpful because it's just a link to a ton of information and it's not clear what specifically anyone should look at.  Feel free to quote and cite the information you feel Answers this question otherwise don't complain about the downvote i issued

Comment: @user763600 - I up voted your comment, because at least you tried to help - Thank You